# How to adjust overall plot width (X-axis size)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been using the following R script, **but the width of the X-axis is too wide**. Could someone kindly help me to adjust the **X-axis** width? Thanks

```
    library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

df <- ToothGrowth
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)
head(df, 6)

# Statistical test
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(len ~ supp) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test


bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "supp", y = "len", fill = "supp", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),width = 0.5)


stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "supp")

bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(
  stat.test, label = "T-test, p = {p}",
  vjust = -1, bracket.nudge.y = 1
) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.15)))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2, 2))
```

Comment: Have you tried resizing the graphics window?

Comment: Hi @ teunbrand  Yes I did but the X-axis  remains wider; i need to reduce the size of X-axis actually

Comment: You can set the aspect ratio of the plot using `theme(aspect.ratio)`.

Comment: Or perhaps pad the right margin? `... + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,3,1,1), "cm"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to adjust the aspect ratio of the theme:

```r
bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(
    stat.test, label = "T-test, p = {p}",
    vjust = -1, bracket.nudge.y = 1
) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.15)))+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2, 2)) +
    theme(
        aspect.ratio = 2
    )
```